# C# XAML Windows Universal Loading Dialog

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Is it possible to create a popup loading dialog in a Windows Universal app, which is similar to an Android progress dialog?

I have a section of my app that might take a bit of time to complete, so I'd like to show the user that the app is actually working.  I want to do this by popping up a dialog overlay of some kind that shadows the background to stop user interaction.

Android Progress Dialog for comparison:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at *Popup* class and *ProgressRing*.

Comment: Use an ContentDialog or UserControl with ProgressRing.

Comment: Use flyout with ProgressRing

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `UserControl`, with background color black and opacity arround 0.6

Then, put `ProgressRing` inside, create a `DependencyProperty` to control the activation of the ring from outside of the UserControl. Put the UserControl in XAML or create it at run time and inject into the Page.

Answer (score 1):

UWP Progress Dialog

```
<UserControl
x:Class="HelperUWP.Controls.BusyIndicator"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:HelperUWP.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LockScreenTextStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.4"/>

    <Grid x:Name="gridBackground"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Background="Transparent" Width="470" Height="120">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="15,5,15,5" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ProgressRing x:Name="progressRing" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsActive="True" 
                         />
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" x:Name="TitleTextBlock"
                       Style="{StaticResource LockScreenTextStyle}" Text="Performing Operation"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

//cs

```
public sealed partial class BusyIndicator : UserControl
{
    private Popup ParentPopup = null;
    public BusyIndicator(string title = "Loading...", SolidColorBrush backgroundColor = null, SolidColorBrush foregroundColor = null)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        TitleTextBlock.Text = title;
        this.Text = title;
        if (backgroundColor != null)
            this.gridBackground.Background = backgroundColor;
        if (foregroundColor != null)
        {
            this.progressRing.Foreground = foregroundColor;
            this.TitleTextBlock.Foreground = foregroundColor;
        } 
    }
    static SolidColorBrush def = Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the BusyIndicator.
    /// </summary>
    public void Close()
    {
        // Close the parent; closes the dialog too.
       // ((Popup)Parent).IsOpen = false;
       if(this.ParentPopup!= null && this.ParentPopup.IsOpen == true)
            this.ParentPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }

    #endregion Public Methods


    #region Public Static Methods
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500) };

    /// <summary>
    /// Locks the screen ans starts the BusyIndicator by creating a popup.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="title">The title to be displayed by the BusyIndicator.</param>
    /// <returns>The BusyIndicator.</returns>
    public void Start()
    {
        // Create a popup with the size of the app's window.
        Popup popup = new Popup()
        {
            Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height,
            IsLightDismissEnabled = false,
            Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width
        };

        // Create the BusyIndicator as a child, having the same size as the app.
        BusyIndicator busyIndicator = new BusyIndicator()
        {
            Height = popup.Height,
            Width = popup.Width,
            Text = this.Text,
        };
        this.timer.Start();
        this.timer.Tick += (f, y) =>
        {
            busyIndicator.Text = Text;
        };
        // Set the child of the popop
        popup.Child = busyIndicator;

        // Postion the popup to the upper left corner
        popup.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 0);
        popup.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0);

        // Open it.
        this.ParentPopup = popup;
        popup.IsOpen = true;

        // Return the BusyIndicator
       // return (busyIndicator);
    }
    //string
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SetMessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string),
        typeof(BusyIndicator), new PropertyMetadata("Loading...", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMessageTextChanged)));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SetMessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SetMessageProperty, value); }
    }
    private static void OnMessageTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BusyIndicator borderControl = d as BusyIndicator;
        borderControl.OnMessageTextChanged(e);
    }
    private void OnMessageTextChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TitleTextBlock.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
    }
    //string
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SetColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SetColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush),
        typeof(BusyIndicator), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Green, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnColorTextChanged)));

    public SolidColorBrush SetColor
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(SetColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SetColorProperty, value); }
    }
    private static void OnColorTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BusyIndicator borderControl = d as BusyIndicator;
        borderControl.OnColorTextChanged(e);
    }
    private void OnColorTextChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TitleTextBlock.Foreground =(SolidColorBrush) e.NewValue;
        this.progressRing.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

//
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCdTN.png)